# calling python function from django template tags

Tags: python, django

How can we pass a variable from a django template tag i.e, i want to do something like this

```
  {{emp.get_names('a')}}
```

`emp` is the object that i am passing from my views

```
 class Emp(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   def get_names(self,var):
      logging.debug(var)          
      names = {}
```

Comment: Mixing logic code with templates is a bad design principle. You should do that in a view. Why would you want that in the templates? Any reason?

Answer (score 4):

You can not call a function that takes a parameter like that. Maybe writing a custom template tag can help, but, why do you need to do it in the template, but not in the view??

[Custom template tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 1):

Django templates are designed to prevent people from doing what you are trying to do. Use a template tag.

Comment: Or, better still, use a view function to do this and provide the data in the template context.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not support calling the function in the default template like this.
maybe you can use some built-in tags like `{{'a'|get_names}}`
You can try to use Jinja2 template,which can let you write python code in it.